# Printing Region With Content in Custom HTML

Tags: hooks, blocks, routes, theming

I am creating a custom first page that is blank and built up from scratch. However I want to print certain regions (e.g. the footer) on this page. How can I grab the region information/content and print it in the html in the welcomegeneratepage function.

```
<?php

//Create the redirect page
function module_name_menu() {
    $items['welcometest'] = array(
        'title' => 'Redirecting',
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'delivery callback' => 'welcome_blank_page'
    );
    return $items;
}

//Function generate the redirect page
function welcome_blank_page() {
    //Get the redirect URL
    //Generate the HTML for the page
    $html = welcomegeneratepage();
    print $html;
}

//Generates the page html
function welcomegeneratepage() {
    print $footer;
    $html = "<html>
                <head>
                    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"".drupal_get_path('module', 'module_name')."/css/module_name.css\">
                    <link rel=\"shortcut icon\" href=\"".variable_get('file_'.file_default_scheme().'_path',conf_path().'/files')."/favicon.ico\" type=\"image/vnd.microsoft.icon\" />
                </head>
                <title>
                        Welcome to ".variable_get('site_name')."
                </title>
                <body>
                   <div class=\"welcomecontent\">
                       <div class=\"welcomemessage\">
                           <h2>Welcome</h2>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                </body>
             </html>";
    return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had any need for a blank page before, but couldn't you just create a new .tpl.php for the front?

Under site configuration, set a node as your front page, then create a copy of page.tpl.php and name it page--node--1.tpl.php (or whatever node ID you have) .

Delete all the divs and containers to make the page blank, and then render regions in php like normal.

> print render($page['your_region']);

Comment: This is a bit new to me. Let's say I want to make the front page called www.example.com/frontpage. Do I first need to create a basic page and then make a page--fontpage.tpl.php? I am using clean urls.

Comment: You would create the page "frontpage" then check its alias, which will be something like node/1 then copy the existing page.tpl.php and rename the copy page--node--1.tpl.php then flush all caches, and edit the copied template as much as you like.